# Use Struts2+rest plugin, get error for cycle in the hierarchy

Tags: json, rest, struts2

> SEVERE: Exception occurred during processing request: There is a cycle in the hierarchy!
>
> net.sf.json.JSONException: There is a cycle in the hierarchy!

I have added the `setcycleDetectionStrategy` in the in the method:

```
public HttpHeaders show() {
    System.out.println("In show.");
    
    JsonConfig jsonConfig = new JsonConfig();
    jsonConfig.setIgnoreDefaultExcludes(false);
    //jsonConfig.setExcludes(new String[]{"requests"});
    jsonConfig.setCycleDetectionStrategy(CycleDetectionStrategy.LENIENT); 
    
    model = service.get(Long.parseLong(id));
              
    return new DefaultHttpHeaders("show");
}
```

But it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it happens with having a instance reference cycle. Some object has an instance variable pointing to another object, which has an instance variable pointing back at the first object. Make sure to avoid the above scenario in your code.

Comment: Thank you, Viswanath D. I have solved it with Jackson.